# SSR compile fails with TailwindCSS "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, static-site

I am making a Github pages site with SvelteKit and Tailwind CSS as a learning project.
I am using Adaptor static to render the site for hosting on github pages so everything ends up getting Server side pre rendered.

Error:

```
[postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')
21:35:57 [vite-plugin-svelte] ssr compile in progress ...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')
    at Parser.parentheses (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:859:65)
    at Parser.parse (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1062:14)
    at Parser.loop (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1043:12)
    at new Parser (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:164:10)
    at Processor._root (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:53:18)
    at Processor._runSync (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:100:21)
    at Processor.astSync (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:145:17)
    at finalizeSelector (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\util\formatVariantSelector.js:125:59)
    at D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\generateRules.js:732:81
    at D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:96:18
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')
    at Parser.parentheses (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:859:65)
    at Parser.parse (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1062:14)
    at Parser.loop (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1043:12)
    at new Parser (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:164:10)
    at Processor._root (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:53:18)
    at Processor._runSync (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:100:21)
    at Processor.astSync (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:145:17)
    at finalizeSelector (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\util\formatVariantSelector.js:125:59)
    at D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\generateRules.js:732:81
    at D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:96:18
Error: Not found: /favicon.ico
    at resolve (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:395:13)
    at resolve (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:236:5)
    at Object.#options.hooks.handle (/@fs/D:/Repositories/myrepo/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:41:55)
    at Module.respond (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:233:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')
    at Parser.parentheses (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:859:65)
    at Parser.parse (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1062:14)
    at Parser.loop (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1043:12)
    at new Parser (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:164:10)
    at Processor._root (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:53:18)
    at Processor._runSync (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:100:21)
    at Processor.astSync (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:145:17)
    at finalizeSelector (D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\util\formatVariantSelector.js:125:59)
    at D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\generateRules.js:732:81
    at D:\Repositories\myrepo\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:96:18
```

I have a Svelte component that has a named tailwind group so that i can do some conditional highlighting.
The basics of the component are like this:

```
<script>
export let id;
export let title;
const setting= `group/${id}`
</script>

<div class="{setting}">
    <div
        class="{`group-hover/${id}:bg-blue-500`}"
    >
        {title}
    </div>
    <slot/>
</div>
```

This works in this REPL that uses tailwind strangely! is this issue just to do with SSR?
https://svelteboard.com/repl

When i made this component I had inline declarations of the class with a prenamed group/name like this:

```
<div class="group/name">
    <div
        class="group-hover/name:bg-blue"
    >
        {title}
    </div>
    <slot/>
</div>
```

that worked fine (but highlighted all instances of the component on hover.)
but when i changed to the newer implementation it breaks with the above error & even when i roll back to a previous check in the error persists.

Am i implementing something wrong,
my tailwind config is unmodified from the svelte + tailwind setup, and svelte config has vitePreprocess and adapterstatic only.

I Tried updating dependencies to latest versions
downgrading postcss to 8.2 (suggested by another question)
reverting to previous revision, (does fix eventually but still cant implement this feature)

Comment: The REPL you shared does not link to anywhere. Can you share a working REPL?

Comment: I have same issue! @notnavindu, error [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-react-tailwind-gdzk4p?file=postcss.config.js)

Comment: @vyvu The question was asked about SvelteKit, and not React. But the reason for the error is the same for both I believe (Check my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs you cannot define dynamic CSS like `group-hover/${id}:bg-blue-500` (Read [here](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support)). All classes should be defined during build time.

You don't need to use nested groups if there is only one group in the component. Take a look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/30245fd281194799b547b405f3638c36?version=3.55.1).

(If this is not the effect you're looking for please add a REPL with a minimum reproducible example)

Comment: Thank you, i will read the docs in more detail.